# Openlayers - Get 404 when calling json file

Tags: json, npm, openlayers

I've a simple local openlayer application via npm on localhost:1234 running.

I trying to use the workshop Example: http://openlayers.org/workshop/en/vector/geojson.html

But I get always "featureloader.js:102 GET http://localhost:1234/data/countries.json 404 (Not Found)"

My json file is for sure found on workshop/data/countries.json.

Why do I get an 404 error?

Comment: Is your server configured to serve `.json` files?  Try renaming it to "countries.json.txt", if that works, it is probably server configuration (most servers serve .text files in their default configuration).

Comment: No there seems to be a problem with finding the folder, do I have to declare something in the package.json or do I have to place the folder data to an other place like src/data ?

Comment: Sounds like the file isn't in a place where it is publicly available on the webserver.  It should be in the data subfolder of the root directory (where the geojson.html file is).

Comment: Thanks, now I've placed the data folder to dist/data, that works, not sure whether this is the right way to do it. So I could go on with my project. best indy